# Shade a line whose format is given as macro's parameter

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

At the moment I can generate this kind of picture with the macro `\mylines` shown below.

[image: not shaded arrows]

But I would like to obtain a result with the second arrow shaded some per cent of the first one:

[image: shaded arrows]

Here is the current code producing the two equal blue arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3 cm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\mylines}[1]{
    %First line full colour
    \draw #1 (0,0) -- (2,1);

    %This second line should have a shaded percentage of the parameter
    \draw #1 (1,0) -- (3,1);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=yellow!20,rounded corners] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
    \mylines{[color=blue, thick, ->]}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The end code —for the different shaded arrows— should look like that:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3 cm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\mylines}[1]{
    %First line full colour
    \draw #1 (0,0) -- (2,1);

    %This second line should have a shaded percentage of the parameter
    %SOME COOL CODE HERE TO DRAW THE SECOND LINE SHADED
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=yellow!20,rounded corners] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
    \mylines{[color=blue, thick, ->]}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Just one more detail: notice that the second arrow is not a transparency, otherwise the blue would mix with the yellow and make something greenish.

Thanks! Any suggestion is pretty welcome.

Comment: One option with an additional argument for the color: `\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3 cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\mylines}[2]{
    \draw #1 [#2] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \draw #1 [#2!50] (1,0) -- (3,1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=yellow!20,rounded corners] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
    \mylines{[thick, ->]}{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo, I appreciate the "extra-parameter" option, but actually the real macro that I am using is quite cumbersome already (I have 16 parameters! :-o) and I would reluctantly add another one. Is there no possibility to do some manipulation **only inside** the macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging into the code of `tikz.code.tex`, I discovered that the TikZ implementation of the `color` key uses internally `\pgfsetcolor{.}`

Which color is "`.`"? Could it be "the current color"? :-)))

Let's try:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3 cm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\mylines}[1]{
    %First line full colour
    \draw#1 (0,0) -- (2,1);

    %This second line should have a shaded percentage of the parameter
    \draw #1 [color=.!20]  (1,0)  --  (3,1);
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=yellow!50,rounded corners] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
    \mylines{[color=blue, thick, ->]}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Yay!

[image: Result]

Comment: It's `xcolor` lingo: in `xcolor` you can refer to the current color with `.`

Comment: Hallelujah! That's THE answer. If somebody reads this comment please consider upvoting this answer: JLDiaz has solved my difficult problem with **just a dot**. Amazing :-o.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3 cm]{standalone}

\def\getpassedcolor#1,#2{#1!20,#2}
\newcommand{\mylines}[1]{
    %First line full colour
    \draw #1 (0,0) -- (2,1);

    %This second line should have a shaded percentage of the parameter
    \draw \getpassedcolor#1 (1,0) -- (3,1);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=yellow!20,rounded corners] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (3.5,1.5);
    \mylines{[color=blue, thick, ->]}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\getpassedcolor` macro accepts arguments separated by a comma, then adds `!20` to the first and returns the reassembled option. It is not very robust (i.e., the `color=blue` *must* be the first option for it to work), but may be sufficient.

[image]

Comment: Cool answer, thank you, I voted you up. And I will use your method if nobody else has something better. As you said this is a quite hard limitation, to always have to put the colour as first parameter. I hope somebody will give the real answer!